# Pros and Cons of Oozie SSH action vs. other actions

Tags: java, hadoop, ssh, apache-spark, oozie

I'd like to understand the advantage of using specialized oozie actions (e.g. java, hive, spark etc.) over SSH action,

In case of an ordinary shell action, the advantage of using specialized oozie actions is obvious: since oozie transforms every action into map-reduce job, shell action is converted into 1-map 0-reduce job, which means that the shell command is going to execute on some randomly chosen cluster node, hence to guarantee correct execution, the shell command should exist on every cluster node, which could get cumbersome

How about SSH action? We explicitly specify a node, hence it is sufficient to have all necessary software and commands installed on that specific node only, so we may execute java, hive, spark and anything else, by using SSH action

Why do we need specialized actions then? What is advantage of using them?

Comment: Well, too bad the SSH action is marked as *deprecated*... After all, why bother building a distributed system with a Resource Manager which places jobs according to Node Labels, data locality, queue priority etc. since we have God-blessed SSH and we can run everything on a single node, with single-threaded programs?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter sorry for asking irrelevant question, was there irony in your comment or you indeed prefer SSH over all other actions?  :-)

Comment: **1.** SSH is indeed deprecated, because it has limitations - you cannot use private-key authentication for instance. Better use a Shell action with an `ssh` command inside  **2.** It was indeed irony. The original use of Oozie was to schedule **MapReduce** jobs (no Launcher). Then the other stuff was added. But that's a lame replacement for a **real** (i.e. Enterprise-grade) scheduler, on an edge node. Because Launcher jobs are a perversion of the Mapreduce framework.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter could you be more specific please, I still couldn't understand what is the difference between using e.g. hive action and using ssh to launch the same hive script on some host

Comment: If Hive is not pre-installed in that host, then it makes a big difference.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter so let's assume that i've preinstalled everything (hive, spark, etc.) on that host beforehand

Comment: So why don't use plain old CRON on that node? Why bother with something else?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter one reasonable justification from my co-workers sounds like: there are lots of job submits coming from all the data service division teams, so using a single node for launching all the jobs will be a burden on that node

Comment: That's exactly why Oozie trandomly distributes the Launcher jobs (thanks to YARN)... Nothing gets "executed" on the node hosting Oozie itself, except the HDFS preparation steps and the e-mails.

Comment: BTW, if you are ready to mess with low-level YARN configuration, you may try to use node "labels" or "tags" to specify on which node(s) you want the Launcher to start. If I am not mistaken "labels" are stable *(used for HDFS tiered storage, or for ML jobs using specific nodes with GPU cards)* but "tags" are still in the works.